# Can you change a variable inside a dictionary during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which stores a list in it and that list has a type of objects in it, which have some member functions.

Then I have a variable which I want to increment as starts at 0, which calls the first position in the list, so it looks like this:

```
index = 0
myDict = {
  "test" : myList[index].foo
}

myDict["test"]()
index += 1
myDict["test"]()
```

What I want to do is that it calls the second place in the list. But the index in the dict seems to be immutable, because it still is referring to the index `0` in the list.

Is there any way to make this work or do I have to come up with an other solution?

Comment: If I am right you wish to pass `index` in the `foo` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with a little change in your code. Instead of assigning the direct function from the `myList[index].foo` assign a lambda which will execute the `myList[index].foo` function inside it.

You can use lambda function like this:

```
index = 0
myDict = {
  "test": lambda: myList[index].foo()
}

myDict["test"]()
index += 1
myDict["test"]()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really not clear what you are *actually* hoping to achieve, but a more pythonic approach generally would be to encapsulate the desired behavior inside a class.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, handle):
        self.inside = handle
        self.index = 0

    def update_index(self, newindex):
         self.index = newindex

    def value(self):
        return self.inside[self.index].foo()

not_a_dict = Thing(mylist)
not_a_dict.value()  # runs mylist[0].foo()
not_a_dict.update_index(1)
not_a_dict.value()  # runs mylist[1].foo()
```

The details of the encapsulation are obviously up to you. For example, you could hardcode `mylist` and not let the user pass in the object to encapsulate, and/or you could make the function to call to obtain the value configurable (pass in a `lambda` callback with the initializer?) etc.